# How to install SweetAlert in Wordpress based website

Tags: wordpress, npm-install, sweetalert2

My website is based on Wordpress and I am using multiple plugins for my purpose.
For some reason I need to modify one of my existing plugins and want to add SweetAlert2 based alert message.

For that I need to install SweetAlert package using command "**npm install sweetalert2**".
But I am not sure where to run this command.

The folder structure of Wordpress based website is like this :

> ~/public_html/wp-content/plugins/

I need to show sweetalert based alert messages from the plugin named '**myCustomPlugin**'.

Do I need to run 'nmp install' command within 'wp-content' folder or within the specific plugin folder or in some other folder ?

For a production based website is it sufficient to run just "**npm install sweetalert2**" command to use it ?  Some other links also say to use "**npm install --save sweetalert2**".

I am bit confused what to run and where to run.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily you put Javascript code into a plugin by putting it into a file named something like

```
.../wp-content/plugins/mycustomplugin/js/sweetalert2.all.min.js
```

You then get your plugin to put it into your HTML by calling [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

This library has zero dependencies, so it doesn't need a build step. Unless your plugin is a Gutenberg editor custom block there's no need to use npm. All you need is a copy of the Javascript code in your plugin directory.

Comment: Beware using case sensitive file and directory names for WordPress code. It will run differently on Windows and other OSes. Stick to lower case and you'll be fine.